# Gnome-subtitles removed from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, video, subtitle

I just notice that Gnome-subtitles is no longer available for Ubuntu 18.04.

Is there an alternative to such tool ? I mean allowing to insert subtitles but also to synchronize them within the video. That was really helpfull !

I had a quick look to Gaupol, but it looks basic, no sync afaiks, and I got a crash when opening a mkv file...

I would really like to be able to install Gnome-subtitles on 18.04...

Thanks.

Comment: You could try using the artful package, it will install & open. Whether it works you'd have to see.. Go here, download the .deb for your arch, then install it with apt. As example I downloaded the amd64 package to my Downloads folder so command would be - `sudo apt install  ./Downloads/gnome-subtitles_1.3-2_amd64.deb`  The package page is here, pick arch in Download section   https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/gnome-subtitles

Comment: Thanks. It looks good and works fine so far (tried in a VM for now).

Comment: The link you posted as a solution at the end of the question (by the way: you should post that as separate answer) is dead. But installing from PPA as in my answer seems to provide the version you mention (1.4.2).

Comment: the new address is **gnomesubtitles.org**

Answer (score 6):

## Subtitles Editors on Ubuntu 18.04

There exists a lot of Subtitles-Editors on Ubuntu 18.04!

Here is a list, and how to install them. Click on the title to visit the homepage:

- [OpenShot Video Editor](https://www.openshot.org/)

  ```
  sudo apt install openshot openshot-doc
  ```
- [kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/en/)

  ```
  sudo install kdenlive kdenlive-data
  ```
- [flowblade](https://github.com/jliljebl/flowblade)

  ```
  sudo apt install flowblade
  ```
- [Subtitle Edit](http://www.nikse.dk/subtitleedit/)

  Installation and Download hints on https://github.com/SubtitleEdit/subtitleedit/releases
- [Jubler](http://www.jubler.org/index.html)

  Install with appimage or from source; see http://www.jubler.org/download.html
- [Subtitle Editor](https://kitone.github.io/subtitleeditor/)

  ```
  sudo apt install subtitleeditor
  ```
- [Subtitle Composer](https://github.com/maxrd2/subtitlecomposer)

  ```
  sudo apt install subtitlecomposer
  ```
- [Gaupol](http://otsaloma.io/gaupol/)

  ```
  sudo apt install gaupol
  ```
- [Devede](http://www.rastersoft.com/programas/devede.html)

  ```
  sudo apt install devede
  ```

---

*If you know better/other tools you are invited to edit this post!*

Comment: Thanks. Subtitle Composer is meant for KDE, but looks really great.

Comment: For me kdenlive is a great environment. Also for editing subtitles.

Comment: @pled: I have Ubuntu with **Gnome desktop**! No prolbem to install it. I've tested it for a mp4 video and it works great! You can install it if you have doubt that it works only on KDE desktop.

Comment: @kavadias:  kdenlive still in the reps ->  https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/kdenlive

Comment: gnome-subtitles it is still here, best for gtk environments: from ppa http://www.gnomesubtitles.org/ubuntu, or deb: https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/disco/universe/base/gnome-subtitles

Answer (score 5):

It is not present in the 18.04 repos, but [**it can be installed from PPA**, as said at gnomesubtitles.org](http://www.gnomesubtitles.org/ubuntu).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pedrocastro/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-subtitles
```

At the date of my post it provides version 1.4.2.

---

It is also **available as a deb package** in various versions, including 1.4.2:

- [UbuntuUpdates.org](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/disco/universe/base/gnome-subtitles)
- [launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-subtitles)
- [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/download/gnome-subtitles).

In subsequent Ubuntu versions, 18.10 and 19.04, Gnome Subtitles made it again to the default repositories.

Comment: "gnome-subtitles"  installes "mono" packages. That's a no-go for me. Better install Aegissub from special ubuntu repository. See: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/08/how-to-install-aegisub-subtitle-editor-in-ubuntu-18-04/